# What is the relation or advantages or reason about these advantages of bundled conductors?

Tags: power, power-electronics, conductors

The book show me the advantages of bundled conductor

1. Decrease the loss from electronic corona
2. Decrease the reactance and voltage drop and increase the efficiency of power transmission
3. Decrease the interference from wireless communication
4. Decrease the potential gradient
5. Decrease the surge impedance

In my thinking ,there is a relation between 1. and 2.

**Relation between 1. and 2.**

> because bundled conductor can decrease the loss from electronic
>   corona, eactance and voltage drop, so of course it can increase the
>   efficiency of transmitting power

**Relation between 2. and 3.**

> because it can decrease the reactance, so it can also decrease the interference from wireless communication

I want to ask :

1. Why can the bundled conductor decrease the loss from electronic corona,is it because it is bundled?
2. Why can the bundled conductor decrease the reactance?
3. Why can the bundled conductor decrease the potential gradient and surge impedance? What is the advantage about them? Does it increase the efficiency of power transmission, decrease the current or something else.

Comment: I don't work in power, so maybe this is obvious, but, what is a "bounded conductor"?

Comment: it is bundled conductor,it seems that my book provide a wrong english name